# Render View in backend dll

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dll

Normally i use this:

```
private byte[] GetInvoiceAsPdf(string id)
{
        var model = Utilities.GetModel(id);
        ViewData.Model = model;

        var view = ViewEngines.Engines.FindView(ControllerContext, "PDFLayout", null);
        byte[] pdfBuf;
        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            var context = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, view.View, ViewData, TempData, writer);
            view.View.Render(context, writer);
            writer.Flush();
            string content = writer.ToString();
            pdfBuf = Utilities.ConvertHtmlToPdf(content);
            if (pdfBuf == null)
                throw new Exception("Invalid pdfBuffer when creating the pdf file.");
        }
        return pdfBuf;
}
```

This works great when i do it inside a controller. However now i need to move it into a DLL file. How can i convert and get it to work from inside a DLL file?

The problems are the `ControllerContext` and the `ViewData`/`TempData`. In the above i set the `ViewData` directly since i am inside a controller and the context i get from the controller.

It's still a MVC project, just that the logic is moved to a DLL file.

Comment: Did you try moving it? What happens? Where does it fail? What's the error message, if any?

Comment: Sorry missed to type in the last piece of information. The problem is the ControllerContext and the ViewData. Both of which are available inside the controller.

Comment: Is it an option to pass those into the function as required parameters?

Comment: That seems to be working great. Just passed the controller into the method. GetPdf(this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting comment as answer:

The solution is to pass all the necessary context information from controller and other resources into the function as parameters (or simply pass controller's instance if it publicly exposes all the necessary contexts), and then use them in the function as usual.  This way the function will have all the necessary information to accomplish its task.